# How to create a random list of numbers using a random.randint for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, random

For my IT class we need to do 10 different tasks and this is the last one that I'm completely stumped on. The goal is to make a list with 20 numbers between -500 and 500. We have two lines of code to sample off of and finish this with.

```
for i in range(10)

     print(i)
```

and

```
import random

    print (random.randint(0,100))
```

Please help me figure this out so I can get a better understanding of the code.

Comment: `rand_list = [random.randint(-500, 500) for _ in range(20)]`?

Comment: `[0] * 20`. This will give you a list with 20 numbers between -500 and 500. If you want a better answer, ask a better question.

Comment: the first snipped show you how to print something multiple times..  the second snippet show how to print a random number..

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @COLDSPEED's comment, if you want a list of 20 number *different* random numbers between -500 and 500.  You can use a while loop to build a set of the random numbers, then convert it to a list.

```
import random

rand_set = set()
while len(rand_set) < 20:
    x = random.randint(-500,500)
    if x not in rand_set:
        rand_set.add(x)

rand_list = list(rand_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
import random
    lst=[]
    for i in range(20):

          lst.append (random.randint(-500, 500))

    print (lst)
```